# How do I send MouseWheelUp and ignore modifiers being held?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to add some behavior that I have bound to shift+MouseWheelUp but occasionally the shift modifier is being applied to what I am sending, here is a simple repro case with output:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#InstallKeybdHook
#UseHook On
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 200


+WheelUp::
    send {a}
return
```

This will output:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The script I am writing is supposed to let me use ctrl+mousewheel to mimic standard mousewheel behavior, but sometimes it will still send ctrl+mousewheel causing things to zoom in and out.

UseHook is something I found suggested for similar problems but had no impact.
Thank you

Edit: On Windows 10

Comment: Cannot confirm this behavior with or without hooks.

Comment: @Bri.H. Thanks for testing, I guess that's why I haven't found any answers to why this happens.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10 with ahk v1.1.26.01. I have a hotkey that is Ctrl+P. If i am slow to release the ctrl (or keep it pressed after pushing and releasing P), the modifier is applied to the inputs send by autohotkey.